# Answer "yes" to ssh-copy-id first time run by script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash

The first time `ssh-copy-id` it will ask

```
# ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub backup@example.com
The authenticity of host 'example.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 39:fb:5e:70:30:33:2b:18:17:e9:4f:2f:91:b5:d2:21.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Is it possible to script this, so the script just will answer yes?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/321181/59925

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `ssh-copy-id` doesn't support the StrictHostKeyChecking option, you can write a script that does:

1. Run `ssh-keyscan` against the target server to get the public key
2. Append that to the known_hosts file
3. Run `ssh-copy-id`

Answer (score 13):

SSH has an option to automatically add any host keys to the trusted hosts file:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no backup@example.com
```

As an alternative, you could do the following:

```
echo "yes \n" | ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub backup@example.com
```

**Edit**: since it appears these solutions don't work with `ssh-copy-id`, you could always create a `~/.ssh/config` file with the following option in it:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

This should work with all SSH connections, regardless if they are invoked through a script or not.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work, and `ssh-copy-id` doesn't have `-o`

Comment: Weird, it does report that switch when issuing `ssh-copy-id -?`

Comment: @sandra `ssh-copy-id` is a script. You can modify it to add `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` or disable that parameter in the ssh_config file.

Comment: Also, you don't need to specify the key location... `ssh-copy-id servername` works fine.

Comment: `sudo sed -i.bak 's/ssh \$/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \$/' $(which ssh-copy-id)`.

Answer (score 1):

This was from a decade ago, but is still a relevant question and doesn't have a functional answer:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub backup@example.com <<< yes
```

You will still need to enter your password.

Just in case someone else stumbles across this old post.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@example.com -y
```

it does not add the host keys to the known_hosts file but lets you copy (or append) the public key to the `authorized_keys` that you want to, if that is the sole purpose here.

Comment: there is no -y option