# Displaying the contents of a Subversion repository

Tags: linux, svn, command-line-interface, solaris

I would like to be able to list out the contents of a subversion repository from a Sun Solaris client. What svn subcommand, or options, do I need to give to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`svn list`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) command will show you the contents of a directory in a subversion repository. For example:

```
svn list svn://svn.example.org/path/in/repos
```

Run `svn help list` at the command line to show details of all the options.

Comment: but please i don't understand the part or contents of this command :- whats we mean by "svn.example.org" .... please if you can give me more details and if you can give me example

Comment: @Mohammad `svn list` takes a repository URL as a parameter (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls for more information about repository URLs). I just included a example URL in my answer. You'll need to use the URL you usually use to access the repository.

Comment: please i want to ask you when i execute this command the following warning appear :- "Warning: the RSA host key for 'example.com.jo' differs from the key for the IP address x.x.x.x '

Comment: @Mohammad This error is being produced by SSH. See http://serverfault.com/questions/2988/error-connecting-to-server-through-ssh

Comment: now after execute this command i found a large number of repository ...and it is complex to find all repository(some svn repository exist in folder within folder within folder and so on) ...if you can help me by give me a method to design a something to write this repository list in excel sheet for example